# Nginx routing not working in sub directory

Tags: nginx

i'm having trouble with routing Klein PHP urls using Nginx.  Here is the current file setup i'm using.

`api --
  index.php
  Klein --
index.php`

And here is the configuration i'm using.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/test.co/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name test.co;

    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri /api/index.php
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;                
    }
}
```

So what i'm trying to do is send all requests after /api/ to /api/index.php with the parameters.  I've tried a TON of things including changing root using an alias, setting up the API on a different server (but then I can't send AJAX requests).  i've also tried proxying the api requests to that server.  If anyone knows how to route a subdirectory please help!

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: When I go to /api this happens to the url. http://invoicr.co/api/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/ also when I make an ajax request it returns a 404 @MichaelHampton

Comment: There are no redirects in your nginx configuration, so check your application.

Comment: There's nothing in my application that redirects, that's what's weird. And it only happens in Chrome. @MichaelHampton